# reactjs why use spread operator in setState

Tags: reactjs

What is the difference between the two syntax?

```
setValues(values => ({
   ...values, [event.target.name]: event.target.value
}))
```

```
setValues({
   [event.target.name]: event.target.value
})
```

Comment: one is giving a function that returns a merged object that adds a new property or sets the value of [event.target.name] with value .value, the other just provides the an object with {[.name]: .value} directly

Comment: You don’t need it in this case, because setState will ONLY overwrite the values it is given. The difference is that in the first case you update the state with a function which is mostly used when updating the state multiple times in a second.

Comment: @Enchew judging from the answers, you should've thrown your own answer into the ring, edit: nevermind, they've been updated

Answer (score 4):

Based upon the name `setValues` I assume you are referring to functional component state. (*`useState` hook updates don't work quite the same as class-based component's `setState` lifecycle function*)

Using the spread syntax allows for maintaining existing state, i.e. the new update `[event.target.name]: event.target.value` is merged into current state.

Given state `{ 'foo': 'bar' }`

```
setValues(values => ({
   ...values, ['bizz']: 'buzz'
}))
```

New state `{ 'foo': 'bar', 'bizz': 'buzz' }`

Without spreading in the previous state you are simply overwriting it with *just* an object `{[event.target.name]: event.target.value}`, so all previous state is lost.

Given state `{ 'foo': 'bar' }`

```
setValues({
  ['bizz']: 'buzz'
})
```

New state `{ 'bizz': 'buzz' }`

There are actually a couple things going on here. First is the **spread syntax**, the other is what is called a **functional update**. Functional updates allow the update to access the current state and make changes. This is a necessity when the *next* state **depends** on the previous state, like incrementing counters, and multiple state updates can be queued up during each render cycle.

```
setCount(count => count +1)
```

In the case of a form component where each property is an independent piece of state, then the following syntax is ok since each update to a field overwrites the current value:

```
setValues({
  ...values,
  [fieldName]: fieldValue
})
```

Answer (score 0):

React may batch multiple `setState()` calls into a single update for performance.

Because `this.props` and `this.state` may be updated asynchronously, you should not rely on their values for calculating the next state.

For example, this code may fail to update the counter:

```
// Wrong
this.setState({
  counter: this.state.counter + this.props.increment,
});
```

To fix it, use a second form of `setState()` that accepts a function rather than an object. That function will receive the previous state as the first argument, and the props at the time the update is applied as the second argument:

```
// Correct
this.setState((state, props) => ({
  counter: state.counter + props.increment
}));
```

We used an arrow function above, but it also works with regular functions:

```
// Correct
this.setState(function(state, props) {
  return {
    counter: state.counter + props.increment
  };
});
```

Read more here on their [official documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous)

Answer (score 0):

the 'values' parameter contains the current values held in state , so by using the spread operator you preserve the values held in the current state and add in new ones.

In the second example you are just setting the state to the event.target.name and overwriting the previously held state.

For example , suppose the app had called setValues three times with three events : event1 , event2 and event3

In the first case you wrote about your state would be { event1, event2, event3 }. in the second case your state would be { event3 }